# How to add data to multidimensional array using array_push function in php

Tags: php, arrays

How to insert data to a multidimensional array using the array_push function in PHP

```
public $transactions =array(array());
function deposit($amount,$date)
    {
        $this->balance += $amount;
        array_push($this->transactions,array("date"=>$date,"type"=>"deposit","amount"=>$amount));

    }
```

The output is -

```
Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/php_workspace/index.php on line 26

    Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/php_workspace/index.php on line 26
```

Comment: You must have assigned a string to `$this->transactions` at some point after you instantiated the object.  This is easier: `$this->transactions[] = array("date"=>$date,"type"=>"deposit","amount"=>$amount);`

Comment: BECAUSE **You must have assigned a string to $this->transactions at some point after you instantiated the object.**

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that `$this->transactions` was assigned to a `String` when you are using `array_push`. The code for push seems correct. 
I would advise you to re-check where do you actually **change** the `$this->transactions` array.

You probably have something like:

```
$this->transactions = '';
```